# How is expected value in entropy derived?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory, mathematical-foundations, entropy

I was self learning about entropy and came across this equation.
$$
H = - \sum p(x) \log p(x)
$$

The equation for entropy in expected value,
$$
H(x) = \operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{X \sim P}[I(x)] = -\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{X \sim P}[\log P(x)].
$$

But the expected value is written as

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i p_i = x_1p_1 + x_2p_2 + \cdots + x_k p_k
$$

Using the above expected value formula, I expected the entropy equation looks something like this

$$H(x)= -\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{x \sim P(x)}[\log P(x)]= - \sum xP(x)\log P(x) $$

where is the $x$ gone in the real entropy formula in summation notation?

Comment: In your last equation, the equation that you think it should look like, what is $x$?

Comment: I am not mathematically skilled and I might be wrong. I took the  $x$ from expected value formula $E[X]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the definition of the expectation of a discrete random variable $Y$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = -\sum_y \Pr[Y = y] \cdot y.
$$
In your case, $Y = \log P(X)$, where $X \sim P$. Therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_y \Pr[\log P(X) = y] \cdot y.
$$
Notice that
$$
\Pr[-\log P(X) = y] = \sum_{x\colon \log P(x)=y} \Pr[X = x] \cdot y = \sum_{x\colon \log P(x)=y} \Pr[X = x] \cdot \log P(x).
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_y \sum_{x\colon \log P(x) = y} \Pr[X = x] \cdot \log P(x) = \sum_x \Pr[X = x] \log P(x) = \sum_x P(x) \log P(x).
$$

Comment: Why $Y=\log P(X)$ is a random variable? $P(X)$ is not a random variable (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300187/is-probability-density-itself-a-random-variable).

Comment: If you apply a (measurable) function to a random variable, you get another random variable.

Comment: So can I think it like a composition $Y=f(g(X))$ where $f= \log$ and $g=P$?

Comment: If you want. You can also think of $\log P$ as a single function.